# Is there any free web based web.config editor?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Does anyone know a web based editor for the web.config? I want to offer the possibility of changing and adding settings through a nice web interface.

**Update:** I am aware of the security issues but still i want to make it possible. The application is an internal app which is not available for outside. I configure authorization within web.config and want be able to administer the users who are able to access the app. Furthermore I have some app settings which i want to be updateable. E.g. mailserver, Connectionstring, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree you probably shouldn't do this....  but in going against the grain since we are all adults here...

It is possible to modify the web.config if your website is running in full trust mode.  If you're hosted on GoDaddy for example then you are probably out of luck.

That being said you could leverage an [admin page I wrote for BlogEngine](http://www.dscoduc.com/post/2008/06/Manage-Files-Extension.aspx) which will allow you to edit any file you have granted the AppPool service permission to edit.  You would probably want to remake this into a user control and then add it to a **protected** url address and/or folder.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to agree with GregD on this point... Exposing the web.config is not a good idea at all. If you really want the user to be able to configure some settings, provide an interface for it, which allows the user to set the values as per requirement. Check out the built-in ASP.NET website administration tool if you need an example.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good reason why the web.config is not readable from the internet.  Don't do it.

**Edited to add**
What is it that you wish to accomplish by opening up the web.config?  The web.config is where you store database connection strings, turn debug off/on, show error messages locally or remotely, etc., etc.  Opening up your web.config to "editing" via a web interface, is really asking for someone to hack it, thus gaining full access to your application.

Comment: The easy knee jerk reaction is the one you have given, however there are plenty of non critical reasons to update a web.config file's contents.  AppSettings, 301 Redirects/UrlRewrite Module, etc.  These values should be things that a non technical admin/SEO person should be able to change without a developer or remoting in to update a config file.